# Hide icons on Fusion Tables Layer

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I'm using Fusion tables with Google Maps API. When map's zoom is 0, 1 or 2 Fusion Tables Layer displays icons instead of polygons. Is there a way to make map act normally (always display polygons despite of zoom level)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Instead, I recommend limiting the zoom of the map using the minZoom parameter:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MapOptions